# What happened to eth.pendingTransactions ? Is there an equivalent?

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, pending-transactions

I am just interested in the number of pending transactions which I usually get from [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/txsPending) , I have seen references to `eth.pendingTransactions` online but I cannot find that or an equivalent in the [api reference](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-AP).

Is there any other place I can access that value programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

From the answer given [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/17698/16301), the [unconfirmed transaction end point](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/ethereum/#unconfirmed-transactions-endpoint) seems like what you want. As explained there,

> The returned object is an array of transactions that haven’t been
>   included in blocks, arranged in reverse chronological order (latest is
>   first, then older transactions follow).

unconfirmed means the pending ones.

Or you can connect to the live network itself via web3 and use `eth.pendingTrnsactions` either by running a full node or using a service like [metamask](https://metamask.io/).

As [@Prashant](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/3446/prashant-prabhakar-singh) suggested in comments,  `eth.pendingTransactions` may be returning pending transaction in mempool of the node you are connected to. And In case your mempool is full, you may miss a tx that is pending =. It may be in pool of others node.

Comment: http://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs returns way too few transactions, I need the total number as an indication of network congestion

Comment: Did you try using injectedweb3 with [metamask](https://metamask.io/)?

Comment: As per my understanding, eth.pendingTransactions gives oending transaction in mempool of the node you are connected to. And In case your mempool is full, you may miss a tx that is pending =. It may be in pool of others node. I maybe wrong.

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh That's a good point. I'll edit the answer. if I could confirm it I'll add a reference. Please do edit if you find any source :)